# php execute sh file

Tags: php, linux, ssh, arguments, shell-exec

I'm attempting to launch a sh file through PHP with arguments, however I cannot get this working at all:

```
<?php
$ip = $_GET['ip'];
$port = $_GET['port'];

echo shell_exec('sh var/www/html/Grant73565/Grant.sh $ip $port')or die("bash didn't work");
echo('Sent!');
?>
```

Running the file through ssh manually works fine like:

./Grant.sh 127.0.0.1 80

However in php it just echo's "Bash didn't work".

It's not to-do with the arguments as far as I know as it's not even launching the file without them.

Comment: do **NOT** do this. you're opening your server to a complete remote compromise. consider `example.com?ip=;rm -rf /`. Enjoy having your server completely destroyed

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double-quotes if you want to include a variable.

```
echo shell_exec("sh var/www/html/Grant73565/Grant.sh $ip $port") or die("bash didn't work");
```

With your current code, anybody can alter the http query and execute anything on your server. This is a major security hole.

The solution is to verify the input. The port will always be numeric so that's simple. You can use a regular expression to verify the IP address.

Comment: I understand the security risk, everything is IP locked anyway. Ill be working on it later. I still get "bash didn't work" with that code.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Have you tried to print out the command and running it through a shell?

Comment: Yes, doing find / -name Grant.sh
returns: /var/www/html/Grant73565/Grant.sh

Comment: So.. include the forward slash in the beginning of the php command? Otherwise you're trying to execute a command relative to the script path.